# Extract a word within a string to a shell variable

Tags: shell, sed

Within a shell script, I read a file where every line starts with "test/version" any number and ":: some further text".

```
test/version 34 :: some text
test/version 9812 :: other text
test/version 2 :: third text
```

After reading the file line by line I want to extract the number to a shell variable - but it doesn`t work so far:

```
filename='logfile.txt'
while read line; do
number=$(sed 's/.*test/version \(.*\)::.*/\1/' "$line")
done
```

Finally, I would like to determine if any number occurs several times or if a number between the smallest and the largest is missing.

Moreover is it possible to read in only x characters of each line, as some can be very long?

UPDATE: The additional text in each line can include every character - also numbers.

Comment: Please limit to one question per question. The `Extract a word within a string to a shell variable` is a one job, the `determine if any number occurs several times or if a number between the smallest and the largest is missing.` is a second question and `is it possible to read in only x characters of each line, as some can be very long?` is a third question.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thanks for your hint. You are right, I will ask the other questions later if necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
while read line; do
  number=$(echo "$line" | sed -E 's,.*test/version ([0-9]+) ::.*,\1,')
  echo $number
done < "$filename"
```

Your main problem was using slash as the sed delimiter and not escaping the slash in the text `test/version`. Rather than escape the slash, just use a different delimiter - I chose the comma.

I also added `-E` ("extended", ie modern) option to make coding the regex easier.

Answer (score 0):

If the input is just separated by spaces, just extract second word with `cut`.

```
while read line; do
    number=$(printf "%s\n" "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2)
    echo $number
done < "$filename"
```